# how to set a custom dirname for multer-imager

Tags: javascript, multer, multer-s3

Anyone know how to set a custom folder name for multer-imager dirname field ? 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-imager

```
const imager = require('multer-imager');
var S3ReziseStorage = imager({
  bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: 'us-east-1',
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var folder = req.body.category ? req.body.category.toLowerCase() : '';
    var dir = 'uploads/'+ folder;
    cb(null, Date.now()+'-'+file.originalname)
  },
  dirname: dir
})


var upload = multer({ storage: S3ReziseStorage });
```

As you can see from above i'm trying to extract the folder name from the req and then pass that to dirname. But right now the variable is in the scope of the filename method and there doesn't seem to be another way to set a custom dirname.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var uploadAvatar = multer({
    storage: imager({
      dirname: 'your_directory_name',
      bucket: 'your_bucket_name',
      accessKeyId: "{{ YOUR KEY-ID}}",
      secretAccessKey: "{{ YOUR SECRET}}",
      region: 'us-west-1',
      filename: function (req, file, cb) { 
        cb(null, 'subfolder/' + file.originalname )             
      },                                    
      s3 : {                                
        Metadata: {                         
          'customkey': 'data'           
        }
      }
    })
  });
```